# Biztalk set WCF MessageHeaders in Biztalk message assignment

Tags: wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I'm trying to set the MessageHeader of a message that my Biztalk orchestration is sending to WCF. The Message Contract looks as follows in the WCF project.

```
 [MessageContract(IsWrapped = true, WrapperName = "PerformTransformationRequestWrapper", WrapperNamespace="http://www.iasreo.com/integration/servicetypes")]
public class PerformTransformationRequest 
{
    [MessageHeader(Namespace = "http://www.iasreo.com/integration/servicetypes")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [MessageHeader(Namespace = "http://www.iasreo.com/integration/servicetypes", MustUnderstand = true)]
    public TransformType TransformType { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://www.iasreo.com/integration/servicetypes")]
    public System.IO.Stream Payload { get; set; }
}
```

TransformType.cs

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.iasreo.com/integration/servicetypes")]
public enum TransformType
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Transform to Excel
    /// </summary>
    [EnumMember]
    ExcelTransform = 1,

    /// <summary>
    /// Transform to PDF
    /// </summary>
    [EnumMember]
    PDFTransform = 2
}
```

I'm creating the message to send to Biztalk in a Message Assignment shape and that code looks as follows:

```
xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(@"<ns0:PerformTransformationRequestWrapper xmlns:ns0=""http://www.iasreo.com/integration/servicetypes""><ns0:Payload>GpM7</ns0:Payload></ns0:PerformTransformationRequestWrapper>");

PerformTransformationRequest = xmlDoc;

xpath(PerformTransformationRequest, "/*[local-name()='PerformTransformationRequestWrapper' and namespace-uri()='http://www.iasreo.com/integration/servicetypes']/*[local-name()='Payload']") = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Input.OuterXml));
```

How can I set the Version and TransformType that MessageHeaders in the WCF MessageContract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the promoted WCF.OutboundCustomHeaders property of the outgoing message

```
OutboundMessage(WCF.OuboundCustomHeaders) = "...";
```

You need to supply the complete WCF Header string as the parameter.

This http://bencode.net/biztalk-custom-wcf-behaviour might be of use to you.

Comment: The one thing I was missing using WCF.OutboundCustomHeaders was adding the namespace for my custom types.